# the no option in my if-else statement isnt working correctly

Tags: c++, if-statement, output

I wrote this code to use the if-else statement but the "no" outputs the same as the yes, I first tried to declare the yes and no variables locally and that fixed the first error I got. But now they are not able to differentiate the output. The condition for yes and no outputs no matter what the input is.

Here is the code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    string name;
    bool answer;
    cout<<"Welcome user 'Divine 9'..."<<"What is your name?"<<endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<endl<<"Hello "<<name<<", my name is Xavier."<<endl<<" I am going to ask you some questions about yourself. Fear not, i will not take any of your information back to the boss man, or store it."<<endl;
    cout<<"Is this okay with you? (yes/no)"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;
    {
        bool yes;
        bool no;
        if(answer==yes)
        cout<<"Great, will proceed with the questions!"<<endl;
        else (answer==no)
        cout<<"That is okay.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So if I type yes, it will output :

"great, will proceed with the questions."

That is okay.

and if I input no, it will output the same.
Can someone please help me figure this out? I thought I had it but I guess I don't

Comment: If you don't get *at least* two warnings for this code, configure your compiler to help you better.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile, unless you also have an extra `;` between `else (answer == no)` and `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

I see two different problems here: the first one is that you are comparing a string with a boolean, the second one is that you are not initialising your boolean variables.
I suggest you to change your if statements in `if(answer=="yes")`
And `if(answer=="no")`
But I don't understand if that is what you are trying to do.

edit: Reading the comments i figured out what the OP means. Of course `answer` should be a `std::string` type.

Comment: Where is he comparing a string with a boolean? He declared `bool answer`.

Comment: You are right. I was confused by the cin stataments

Comment: @Barmar Anyway this answer points out into the better direction, and covers the OP's confusion about boolean vs string variables input!

Answer (score 1):

You don't put a condition after `else`. You just put a statement or block -- the condition is just that the previous `if` failed. So it should be:

```
if (answer == yes) {
    cout<<"Great, will proceed with the questions!"<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"That is okay, still love the Gamma Sig ladies, especially that_girl_teejay :-)";
}
```

If you want to test another condition, you use `else if (condition)`.

Another problem: you never initialized `yes` and `no`. It should be:

```
bool yes = true;
bool no = false;
```

But these are pretty useless. You don't need to compare booleans with anything, you can just use them directly in the condition:

```
if (answer) {
    cout<<"Great, will proceed with the questions!"<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"That is okay, still love the Gamma Sig ladies, especially that_girl_teejay :-)";
}
```

Note that when you input a `bool` with `cin >> answer`, you can't type `yes` or `no`. `bool` only allows inputs `1` (for `true`) and `0` (for `false`). If you want to allow words as answers, you should input a string and compare with strings. It should be:

```
string answer;
...
const string yes = "yes";
const string no = "no";
if (answer == yes) {
    cout<<"Great, will proceed with the questions!"<<endl;
} else if (answer == no) {
    cout<<"That is okay."<<endl;
} else {
    count<<"Please enter yes or no."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: ok will make the correction and see if it works, thanks

Comment: i tried this and it didnt work either  :
cout<<"Is this okay with you? (yes/no)"<<endl;
cin>>answer;
{bool yes = true;
bool no= false;
if(answer==yes)
{
cout<<"Great, will proceed with the questions!"<<endl;}
else
cout<<"That is okay, still love the Gamma Sig ladies, especially that_girl_teejay :-)";}

return 0;
}

Comment: Are you entering `0` or `1`?

Comment: @Barmar As I've read from the original posting, I'd suspect they're entering `yes` or `no`. All that `yes`/`no` boolean variable stuff is pretty useless!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know, but I explained in my answer that that won't work. I'm asking whether he fixed that when he implemented my corrections.

Comment: @Barmar No you don't clearly solve that kind of the OP's confusion in your answer IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar That's better ...